# VSCode: New line after curly brace for JSX

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, prettier

How can I get VSCode (using prettier formatter) to insert a line after the opening and before the closing curly brace in this situation?

Current Formatting (what vscode is doing now when I format):

```
   {degreeRequirements.map(requirementCategory => {
      console.log(requirementCategory);
      return (
        <DegreeRequirementCategory
          requirementCategory={requirementCategory}
        />
      );
    })}
```

Ideal Situation:

```
   {
      degreeRequirements.map(requirementCategory => {
         console.log(requirementCategory);
         return (
           <DegreeRequirementCategory
             requirementCategory={requirementCategory}
           />
         );
       })
   }
```